# Formatting AttributeError in __getattr__

Tags: python

If a class defines a `__getattr__` method it needs to raise an `AttributeError` if the requested attribute was not found.

However, if one simply executes `raise AttributeError()` the usual error message is missing.

Currently I am doing the following instead:

```
raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(self.__class__.__name__, name))
```

This however is a lot of boiler plate code and has the potential for inconsistent error messages if the python interpreter was e.g. localised.

Is there any way to get python take care of assembling the error message the same way it does when no `__getattr__` method is defined?

Answer (score 3):

Most such cases in the standard library don't bother with the message and just use the name as an argument:

```
raise AttributeError(attr)
```

letting the traceback tell the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The default error (along with the formatted message) is usually raised in `object.__getattribute__`.  As such, this is the method that you want to call if you want python to do the error formatting for you.

You can do something cute and try to call `__getattr__` on the super class.  If `__getattr__` doesn't exist, then you can fall back to using `__getattribute__` which will take care of formatting the error:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return super(Foo, self).__getattr__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr)


f = Foo()
x = f.bar
```

Of course, this swallows all (possibly helpful) errors that might get raised in the super class's `__getattr__`, so use this carefully...

If you're at a point in your code where you *know* that the current class should be raising a appropriately formatted `AttributeError`, you can just do something a little more direct:

```
class RaiseAlwaysExample(BaseClass):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if True:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)  # Raise appropriately formatted attribute error.
```

Comment: `object` has no `__getattr__`.

Comment: @user2357112 -- As usual, you're completely correct.  I've updated with an alternative solution.

Comment: Better. Don't forget to `return` the attribute value.

Comment: Yes, either `return` something or `assert False` at the end of the method; don't just let control flow off the end.

Comment: I don't like the smelly explicit calling of parent's supposed `__getattr__` and, even more so, `__getattribute__`. Why not `getattr()`?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev -- Within an overridden `__getattr__`, calling the parent's `__getattr__` is the right thing to do.  If you use `getattr`, python will call `__getattr__` on the current class again and you'll end up with infinite recursion.  The reason to go on and use `__getattribute__` is because OP wants message on the exception to be exactly the same as if `__getattr__` wasn't present.  I agree that this is an odd requirement and if it can be relaxed, then doing something like your answer is probably completely adequate.

Comment: @mgilson okay, I see that `__getattribute__` is required to delegate to the parent, so 1)calling `super().__getattribute__` with the idea that it would call `object.__getattribute__` and 2)`except AttributeError:` in both cases if there's no `__getattr__` and if `__getattr__` raises the exception -- are both fair game. I still think they warrant some explanatory text in the answer since they're so non-obvious.

Comment: @mgilson OTOH, _"Of course, this swallows all (possibly helpful) errors that might get raised in the super class's `__getattr__`"_ doesn't seem a legitimate concern to me: _the only_ "helpful error" that a `__getattr__` is allowed to raise is `AttributeError`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev -- Sure, but the _message_ that is associated with that `AttributeError` would be lost.

Comment: @mgilson but the only useful thing an `AttributeError`'s message contains is the attribute's name -- which we already have. And per my previous comment, we don't care if the exception is raised due to the target attribute or `__getattr__` itself missing.